# what is maximum polygons a 3d model created in 3ds max can have if it is to be loaded to sandy

Tags: sandy3d

I am writing a code to load a model created in 3ds max into sandy. Can any one please tell me what is the largest polygon count sandy can support. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well technically it's unlimited, but you don't want to load too many, as that would seriously impact performance, and it would run extremely slow. Especially flash.

I saw that 3ds max 2008 had a limit of ~6 million.

The best way to find this out is by trial and error, if you really need to know.

Comment: You might find the limitation imposed within the flash itself, the browser, or purely on the limitations of your or the user's hardware.

Why do you need to find out what the limit is?

Comment: I want to find out the limitations imposed by flex or sandy, not the limitation of 3DS Max. I'm using 3DS max to create the models

Comment: Why do you need to find this limitation? Either way all you have to do is find out by trial and error.